# Should we have a newline after method name in Java?

Tags: java

This is one doubt regarding best practice in Java. Is it good idea to leave a blank line after method name. Eg. say I have following code

```
public void print(String str) {
    System.out.println("Hello word" + str);
}
```

So, here is it good practice to leave a blank line before Print statement? I checked Java doc regarding that. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-141388.html

It says, Blank should be :-
Between the local variables in a method and its first statement

I am not sure if it means the same thing that I am asking or it is something else.

Anything you can tell would be great.

Comment: A method parameter is not considered a "local variable". `print() { String a="a";System.out.println("b" + a);}`, then `a` is a local variable. But even that, could be considered just an opinion.

Comment: It's also a method, not a function, a function has a very different meaning in Java.

Comment: I think it is harsh to down-vote this question, The oracle coding conventions are quite widely used and the wording of that piece does seem easy to misunderstand. I would not be surprised if others are confused by it. Perhaps advice or edit suggestions would be more appropriate.

Comment: coding conventions are largely opinion based. Unless it's edited to clearly reflect a question on a specific convention and wording, it should be closed as being primary opinion based. At the moment it is asking about 'good practice'

Comment: When you use, for example, NetBeans, you can press "Shift+Alt+F" and it automatically aligns all your code. The same function "Format" is present in Eclipse I think.

Comment: @RyanTheLeach I agree some editing would be beneficial but it is linking to a specific and widely used convention that is somewhat ambiguous.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Short answer: No. That piece of the standard is meaning that you should leave a gap between the local variables and the first statement *inside* the method.

i.e:

```
String someText = "text";
String moreText = "more text";
// gap here
System.out.println(someText + " " + anotherText);
```

Answer (score 26):

The standard doesn't apply in your case because you have no local variables.  So I'd say

```
// YES
public void print(String str) {
    System.out.println("Hello word" + str);
}
```

is just fine.  Much better than:

```
// NO
public void print(String str) {
                                      // This blank line is unnecessary
    System.out.println("Hello word" + str);
}
```

The standard is talking about something like this:

```
// YES
public void print(String str) {
    double rand = Math.random(100);
                                        // A blank here is good
    System.out.println("Hello word" + str + "; today's number is " + rand);
}
```

being preferred over

```
// NO
public void print(String str) {
    double rand = Math.random(100);
    System.out.println("Hello word" + str + "; today's number is " + rand);
}
```